# If one column is null, replace another column with null as well

Tags: sql

I am joining two tables, case and user. My problem is that I want to sensor the user's name and location if he/she is working at location B-D.

**I want this**

[image: Default]

**To look like this**

[image: Censored]

This is my code so far, but the name is not censored:

```
SELECT 
c.CaseID, 
c.Category, 
u.User, 
CASE 
    WHEN u.Location != "A" THEN null
    ELSE u.Location
END as Location

FROM cases c

JOIN c.userID on u.userID
```

Comment: amazing how the edit made that post so much easier to answer @GMB

Answer (score 5):

Use the same case statement for user column too.

```
SELECT 
c.CaseID, 
c.Category, 
CASE 
    WHEN u.Location != "A" THEN null
    ELSE u.User
END as User,
CASE 
    WHEN u.Location != "A" THEN null
    ELSE u.Location
END as Location
FROM cases c...... <Your remaining query>
```

Comment: `case` _expression_.